# How to get all possible slices of a 1D numpy array depending on input

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array

```
a = np.arange(12)
>>> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

I am trying to calculate all possible cumsums like this

```
np.cumsum[2:] + np.cumsum[:-2]
np.cumsum[3:] + np.cumsum[:-3]
...
np.cumsum[11:] + np.cumsum[:-11]
```

How can I achieve this without a loop
I tried doing

```
starts = np.arange(2,12)
np.cumsum[starts:] + np.cumsum[:-starts]
but I get this error
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

How do I do this without a for loop

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to calculate moving average of all possible time frames within the length of a sequence. For example, if I had an array size of 10, I could do moving average 1 period (doesn't make sense) , moving average 2 periods, 3 periods...10 periods. How do I accomplish this. I want to calculate the moving average from 2 to n where n is the size of the sequence

Comment: You're final results don't have the same length which means you cannot do this in a decent vectorized manner. Maybe a list comprehension would be the best choice. Also note that `np.cumsum` is a function object and is not subscriptable you can do `array[:index].cumsum()` instead.

Comment: Also, please add your expected output, at least for one output so that we see what's the exact desired result.

Comment: @Kasramvd thanks I added the expected output, I want to do a moving average of the values for all periods possible within the sequence of the array, If there are 10 values, we can do 10 moving averages of which the first one doesnt make sense, I ll update the question

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood the question completely, here's something you could use as a starting point.

You need arrays with uniform sizes to be able to exploit vectorization. You cannot do it with simple slicing but zero padding can help in this case:

```
In [3]: a = np.arange(12)

In [4]: a
Out[4]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])

In [15]: starts = np.arange(2,12)

In [18]: left = np.stack([np.pad(a,(0,s),mode="constant")[s:] for s in starts])

In [19]: left
Out[19]: 
array([[ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 9, 10, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [10, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Here you need to also shift everything to the left to get proper alignment:

```
In [27]: right = np.stack([ np.roll(np.pad(a, (s,0), mode="constant")[:-s], -s) for s in starts ])

In [28]: right
Out[28]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Now you can use vectorized `np.cumsum` for the intensive part

```
In [41]: np.cumsum(left, axis=1) + np.cumsum(right, axis=1)
Out[41]:
array([[  2,   6,  12,  20,  30,  42,  56,  72,  90, 110, 110, 110],
       [  3,   8,  15,  24,  35,  48,  63,  80,  99,  99,  99,  99],
       [  4,  10,  18,  28,  40,  54,  70,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88],
       [  5,  12,  21,  32,  45,  60,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77],
       [  6,  14,  24,  36,  50,  66,  66,  66,  66,  66,  66,  66],
       [  7,  16,  27,  40,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55],
       [  8,  18,  30,  44,  44,  44,  44,  44,  44,  44,  44,  44],
       [  9,  20,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33],
       [ 10,  22,  22,  22,  22,  22,  22,  22,  22,  22,  22,  22],
       [ 11,  11,  11,  11,  11,  11,  11,  11,  11,  11,  11,  11]])
```

Now you probably need to clean up the result to get what you want, but I'm still not sure, it would be great if you could post the expected output. Something like this should do:

```
In [50]: [ row[:-s] for row,s in zip(csum,starts) ]
Out[50]: 
[array([  2,   6,  12,  20,  30,  42,  56,  72,  90, 110]),
 array([ 3,  8, 15, 24, 35, 48, 63, 80, 99]),
 array([ 4, 10, 18, 28, 40, 54, 70, 88]),
 array([ 5, 12, 21, 32, 45, 60, 77]),
 array([ 6, 14, 24, 36, 50, 66]),
 array([ 7, 16, 27, 40, 55]),
 array([ 8, 18, 30, 44]),
 array([ 9, 20, 33]),
 array([10, 22]),
 array([11])]
```

Comment: upvoted! thanks for the effort but I am trying to do this without for loops in a vectorized manner, given say an array with 25 elements i want to find all possible moving averages, usually you would do a moving average with a particular timeframe but how to do all

Comment: Note that loops are used only for the problem setup part that should be negligible with respect to the cumsum computation

Comment: @PirateApp by the way, shouldn't you subtract the second cumsum from the first instead of summing if a running mean is what you're aiming for? something like `(np.cumsum(a[:n]) - np.cumsum(a[:-n])) / n`

Answer (score 1):

It is not what you asked for.  But if you are looking for a simpler solution , you can use the pandas approach.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' :np.arange(11)})  # your data 
window_lengths = np.arange(2,len(a))  # define window lengths from 2 to n
[rolling_win.mean() for rolling_win in [df.rolling(length) for length in window_lengths]]
```

**output :**

```
 [      a
     0   NaN
     1   0.5
     2   1.5
     3   2.5
     4   3.5
     5   4.5
     6   5.5
     7   6.5
     8   7.5
     9   8.5
     10  9.5,       a
     0   NaN
     1   NaN
     2   1.0
     3   2.0
     4   3.0
     5   4.0
     6   5.0
     7   6.0
     8   7.0
     9   8.0
     10  9.0,       a
     0   NaN
     1   NaN
     2   NaN
     3   1.5
     4   2.5
     5   3.5
     6   4.5
     7   5.5
     8   6.5
     9   7.5
     10  8.5,       a
     0   NaN
     1   NaN
     2   NaN
     3   NaN
     4   2.0
     5   3.0
     6   4.0
     7   5.0
     8   6.0
     9   7.0
     10  8.0,       a
     0   NaN
     1   NaN
     2   NaN
     3   NaN
     4   NaN
     5   2.5
     6   3.5
     7   4.5
     8   5.5
     9   6.5
     10  7.5,       a
     0   NaN
     1   NaN
     2   NaN
     3   NaN
     4   NaN
     5   NaN
     6   3.0
     7   4.0
     8   5.0
     9   6.0
     10  7.0,       a
     0   NaN
     1   NaN
     2   NaN
     3   NaN
     4   NaN
     5   NaN
     6   NaN
     7   3.5
     8   4.5
     9   5.5
     10  6.5,       a
     0   NaN
     1   NaN
     2   NaN
     3   NaN
     4   NaN
     5   NaN
     6   NaN
     7   NaN
     8   4.0
     9   5.0
     10  6.0,       a
     0   NaN
     1   NaN
     2   NaN
     3   NaN
     4   NaN
     5   NaN
     6   NaN
     7   NaN
     8   NaN
     9   4.5
     10  5.5]
```

Comment: upvoted! thanks, i considered a for loop several times but I was quite curious if this can be done in a vectorized manner, I even tried as_strided but still no luck so far